# self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES and go back with swipe gesture on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I write the codes below in my UIViewController that uses UINavigationController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>) self;
}
```

I build and run my app,

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

above that works correctly, but

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>) self;
```

that one DO NOT works.

So, I re-write the code below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f)]];
    backBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
}
```

It works correctly.

However, I want to use the first example.
The first one clearly express what I want to do.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried first assigning the delegate & then hiding the `back` button?

Comment: It seems good! When I do it in `viewDidLoad`, it doesn't work. However, in `viewWillAppear`, it works correctly. And next question occur. Now, I'm in `NavigationController-1`, and I want to go back to `NavigationController 2`. Then I try to move from "2" to "1". However, its a  just try. I do not complete that and finally I get back to "2". and see the UINavigationBar, strange dots appears. why I get that...

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad`, the view controller is not yet contained in a navigation controller, so the `navigationController` property is `nil`, which is why that line has no effect.

That said, assigning the delegate of `UINavigationController`'s `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is not good practice (I'm pretty sure it expects to be assigned to the navigation controller). Try disabling the gesture recognizer in `viewWillAppear:` instead:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```